# Using .findBy() with Ember-data-populated array controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, qunit

### Background

I'm writing some functional tests to test that my router is navigating and loading my models correctly. So far, so good--even in light of this issue.

I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magLM/2/), for your enjoyment. It doesn't work--I've never had much luck with jsfiddle and ember, in spite of forking [@wagenet](http://jsfiddle.net/wagenet/kcjzw/). But it has more source code to help get an overall picture of what I have going on.

### My Biggest Gripe

So my biggest gripe is that the following code doesn't work to retrieve an element with a known id from a controller:

```
var controller = App.__container__.lookup("controller:postsNew");
var type1Option = controller.get("controllers.types").findBy("TYPE1");
```

I've done something similar in the setupController hook and it worked. But that was within the context of my application, so it looked more like this:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.controllerFor("types").findBy("TYPE1");
}
```

But even that doesn't work anymore! I'm also working outside my app, now--in a qunit test. So I have to use `App.__container__.lookup()`, according to everything I've read.

### The Root?

What I've found is that `controller.length` is undefined--which is causing `.findBy()` to fail. And the items exist in the array...at least, I can see them by doing `controller.toArray()`.

### The Temporary Solution

The following is what I have to do instead:

```
var controller = App.__container__.lookup("controller:postsNew");
var type1Option = null;
$.each(controller.get("controllers.types").toArray(), function(index, elm) {
    if (elm.get("id") === "TYPE1") {
        type1Option = elm;
        return true;
    }
});
```

This is obviously not as clean.

### So, Questions

- Is `.findBy()` broken?
- Am I doing `.findBy()` wrong?
- How do you use `.findBy()`??

Comment: Ember Array [includes](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_includes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`findBy` takes 2 arguments, property key to test against, and value to find (it defaults to true if not passed in).  Essentially you are searching for a model with a property `TYPE1` that's `true`

You're probably looking to do this

```
findBy("id", "TYPE1")
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_findBy

> Returns the first item with a property matching the passed value. You can pass an optional second argument with the target value. Otherwise this will match any property that evaluates to true.

Comment: Oh. my. goodness. This was just a result of looking at the same bit of code for too long, I suppose. Thank you!

Comment: @Kingpin2k : If the passed value is through variable, its not working as expected. Any idea?